# How to use one sequence for all table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sequence

When I'm creating tables in an SQLite database, separate sequences are automatically created for each table.

However I want to use one sequence for all tables in my SQLite database and also need to set `min` and `max` values (e.g. `min=10000` and `max=999999`) of that sequence (`min` and `max` means start value of sequence and maximum value that sequence can increment).

I know this can be done in an Oracle database, but don't know how to do it in SQLite.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @muistooshort i have examined SQLite database using `SQLite Database Browser`. there are separate distinct sequences in `sqlite_sequence` table for all tables in my database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this: SQLite automatically creates sequences for each table in special `sqlite_sequence` service table.

And even if you somehow forced it to take single sequence as source for all your tables, it would not work the way you expect. For example, in PostgreSQL or Oracle, if you set sequence to value say `1` but table already has filled rows with values `1`,`2`,..., any attempt to insert new rows using that sequence as a source would fail with unique constraint violation.

In SQLite, however, if you manually reset sequence using something like:

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 1 WHERE name = 'mytable'
```

and you already have rows `1`,`2`,`3`,..., new attempts to insert will NOT fail, but automatically assign this sequence maximum existing value for appropriate auto-increment column, so it can keep going up.

Note that you can use this hack to assign starting value for the sequence, however you cannot make it stop incrementing at some value (unless you watch it using other means).

Comment: if the column using auto-increment the duplication will not happen because next time you will use the sequence, SQLite will generate a number that is the maximum in the table + 1.
I am not sure if this happens only for columns that are primary key or have a unique constraint, but this is usually the case for auto-increment columns.

Comment: @RobMcZag: this is exactly what I said - in SQLite, sequence will be automatically assigned next possilble value if current value is already present in the table. Current algorithm is max+1

Comment: yes, but trying to generalize. In your example you set the sequence to 1, but you have id=1 in your rows. I was trying to point out that in SQLite you will get the max+1 in any case, even if you set the sequence to a number that is not in the table and so one could think to be available.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a bad idea.

The performance of database queries depends on predictability, and by fiddling with the sequence of indexes you are introducing offsets which will confuse the database engine.

However, to achieve this you could try to determine the lowest sequence number which is higher than or equal to any existing sequence number:

```
SELECT MAX(seq) FROM sqlite_sequence
```

This needs to be done after each INSERT query, followed by an update of all sequences for all tables:

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq=determined_max
```